# Can I have three different apps in single project? or Should I have three different apps like the admin-app, customer-app, and vendor-app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am working on a final year project (flutter app) and am very much confused about what should I do. Whether should I have three different apps like the admin app, customer app, and vendor app like Foodpanda has or I should combine these three apps in a single app project? Please guide me with the reason which one is better? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on your app complexity. Three different apps would be recommended if all three of them have different set of features and vary a lot compared to each other. Else you could make single app and implement an authentication system which detects the type of user logging in. After determining the type you could direct them to their specific screens. Personally, I would recommend three different apps. Ultimately it depends on your requirements and the choice is yours.

Comment: Is it possible to have a single firebase project that can handle three different apps?

Comment: yes, that is possible. you can have many apps in single firebase project.

Comment: If I want three apps in a single app project then how can I know which user is logging in example customer, rider, or vendor? please guide me in this situation, thank you.

Comment: Just like you store a user's password and email in the database, you can store a type value (String) for them. Everytime they login, you can return the user's type and depending on the response you can do the rest.

Comment: My advice to you is that it will be faster to use the user tobacco shared preferences structure.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @AbhishekThulasi!  :)

Comment: @ÖmerSeyfettinYavuzyiğit would you please guide me that how can I use shared preferences in determining different users like admin, customer, rider, vendor, etc. As they are different users so, there are going to be different screens and bottom navigations.  For example, if the customer signs up and logs in then the screens should be related to him, and if the rider or vendor logs in then screens should be related to them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add multiple projects in single database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).